# Custom view not working Testfligt on Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, xcode11.4

I create and display a custom view with the code snippet below. It was running smoothly before Xcode 11.4. Although it works while debugging at Xcode 11.4, the view does not occur when I upload it to testfligt.
Has anyone experienced such a problem?

```
if UIScreen.main.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIScreen.main.scale)) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
} else{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(vView.frame.size)
}

vView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
vView.setNeedsDisplay() // add this and solve problem
let imageR = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext() 
return imageR
```

Comment: From Xcode edit your scheme to release mode you can try to understand the problem more easily instead of having to upload a version to testflight each time

Comment: @MickaelBelhassen thank you. This answer will make my job easier.